# Is there an event to detect switch on/off session-storage in browser?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I've application which requires session storage to work. I would detect dynamically when user switches this on/off.

Is there an browser event to listen or how can I do it different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `if(window.sessionStorage)`

You cannot bind an event to something outside the DOM